# Structure of curated data?

Tags: curated-data

Is there a way to programmatically access the structure of curated data present in Mathematica (for each type of information, for example for CountryData or ChemicalData) that would allow access to any kind of available information ? This would also allow the possibility to build generic graphical interfaces for accessing the data.

Comment: A few things I've worked on recently might help with this: this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146139/38205 lets you pull the data from a WDX file if you want to circumvent the paclet structure and this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146221/38205 will let you build your own curated data paclets.

Answer (score 5):

This howto illustrates how to use curated data:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/UseCuratedData.html

Basically the general structure of curated data seems to be Classes>Entities>Properties.

For FinancialData, this variable outputs available properties

```
DataPaclets`FinancialDataDump`FinancialProperties
```

And you get different classes of available data using

```
FinancialData["Classes"]
```