# How to provide data to users in a way similar to Mathematica's curated data

Tags: data, curated-data

How can one go about implementing a custom data backend usable by *Mathematica*? For example something like `CountryData` or `FinancialData`?

I would like to expose our data backend as a service with similar access logic used in the above mentioned data libraries.

Comment: Check out [this link] (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23427/access-curated-or-locally-stored-data-with-curated-data-functions)

Comment: Another [related link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15492/3066).

Comment: Here's a way to imitate the way WRI does it more-or-less exactly: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146221/38205

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More of a long comment...

You can easily write a function that will enable your end users to Import data from your custom backend.

```
customData[param1_]:= Import[...]
customData[param1_, param2_]:= Import[...]
customData[param1_, param2_, param3_]:= Import[...]
```

Using different parameter sets in your function definition can give you all the kinds of flexibility you see in `CountryData` or `FinancialData`.

Placing you functions in an automatically loaded package would make the user experience even better.

I/we would really need some better idea of what you have tried to provide a more complete and useful answer.