# Extracting data from Data paclet

Tags: curated-data, customization, undocumented, paclets

In the `$UserBasePacletsDirectory` there are lots of paclets that have only `Data` as an element. These are loaded via the `` DataPaclets` `` functionality using the standard form:

```
DataPaclets`ImportData[
 pacletName<>"_"<>dataPart<>".wdx",
 DataPaclets`GetDataPacletResource[pacletName<>"_"<>dataPart, 
  dataSubpart<>".wdx"]
 ]
```

E.g.:

```
DataPaclets`ImportData[
 "ChemicalData_Index",
 DataPaclets`GetDataPacletResource[
  "ChemicalData_Index",
  "Properties.wdx"
  ]
 ]
```

This only works though when the .wdx file has the standard `"Expression"` part, e.g.:

```
DataPaclets`ImportData[
 "ChemicalData_Index",
 DataPaclets`GetDataPacletResource[
  "ChemicalData_Index",
  "Index.wdx"
  ]
 ]
```

this fails.

On the other hand for these indices we can pull stuff like:

```
DataPaclets`ImportData[
 "ChemicalData_Index",
 DataPaclets`GetDataPacletResource[
  "ChemicalData_Index",
  "Index.wdx"
  ],
 {"DataIndex", "Sources", "Data"}
 ]
```

Which will give us a long set of data specifying in what part we can find the actual data. For example we'll get something like `"Part01" -> { ... }` which seems to mean that the data for keys listed in that list can be found via:

```
DataPaclets`ImportData[
 "ChemicalData_Part01",
 DataPaclets`GetDataPacletResource[
  "ChemicalData_Part01",
  "Part01.wdx"
  ],
 {"DataTable", "Index"} (* Note that now we find the DataTable element *)
 ]
```

The problem is that the return from this is just a long list of really large ints and I have no idea what they mean and how to convert them to proper data.

I want to make my own Data paclet, but unfortunately I need to know how to export my data to make it work.

Does anyone know how to convert this? I really have no idea what it's supposed to be as the numbers range from around 440k to roughly 6 mil

Answer (score 3):

#### Data Import

After doing some digging into the WDX export function (`` System`Convert`WDXDump`ExportWDX ``), for a `"DataTable"` one finds that the `"Index"` property is just the stream positions of a list of elements with duplicate elements removed (done via the `"DetectDuplicates"` option). Hence the observation that the `"Index"` is primarily increasing with some discrete jumps.

The objects themselves have varying byte representations coming from `` System`Convert`WDXDump`writeWDXObject `` and can be read with `` System`Convert`WDXDump`readWDXObject ``.

This means we can write something import the actual WDX data by something like this:

```
wdx =
  DataPaclets`GetDataPacletResource[
   "ChemicalData_Part01", "Part01.wdx"
   ];
idx =
  DataPaclets`ImportData[
   "ChemicalData_Part01",
   wdx,
   {"DataTable", "Index"}
   ];
read[piece_, n : _Integer : 1] :=

 With[{strm = OpenRead[wdx, BinaryFormat -> True]},
  SetStreamPosition[strm, idx[[piece]]];
  (Close[strm]; #) &@
   Table[System`Convert`WDXDump`readWDXObject@strm, n]
  ]
```

And if we want the 15-25th expressions in the data underlying (in this case the first chunk of the data underlying[`ChemicalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChemicalData.html)) we can get it:

```
In[439]:= read[15, 10] // NewlineateInput

Out[439]= {
 "B2Be",
 "6.1",
 {1566},
 {},
 {{"Be", 29.419}, {"B", 70.58}},
 {{"Be", 1}, {"B", 2}},
 "EU235-443-0",
 {-1, -1, 2},
 "beryllium boride",
 "Gmelin171277"
 }
```

This then corresponds to the some stuff in the `"Keys"` and `"Properties"` portions of the data.

Seeing as my question was really about the export form that problem will be left to the reader.

#### Data Export

In terms of export `` System`Convert`WDXDump`ExportWDX `` tells us how to set that up. All we need is to specify the `"Keys"`, `"Properties"` and `"Data"` parameters. Any missing parameters will default to an empty list. The code suggests that an `"Attributes"` property should be applicable too as a list of options with string keys. Any way this gets the job done for me:

```
Export[
 "file.wdx",
 {
  "Keys" ->
    Keys@entityStore["Entities"],
  "Properties" ->
    Thread@List@Keys@entityStore["Properties"],
  "Data" ->
    Normal@Map[Values, Values@entityStore["Entities"]]
  },
 "DataTable"
 ]
```