# Can I build my own curated data function?

Tags: curated-data, entity, paclets

I love the huge curated datasets, but they don't cover everything. I have my own huge dataset which is too much to distribute as an [`EntityStore`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityStore.html) so is there a way to build my own analog of, say, [`ElementData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ElementData.html)?

Answer (score 27):

#### Update: Template Notebook

I finally got around to finishing my curated data template notebook. You can see it [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/Templates/CuratedDataTemplate.nb)

Currently it only supports single-type data paclets, but a template for [multi-type curated data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146894/custom-curated-data-function-for-multiple-datasets?noredirect=1&lq=1) is in the works and I'll test that with my accumulated Stack Exchange data.

In the meantime, I took some arbitrary airline safety data and turned it into a paclet. [This](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/AirlineSafetyData_paclet.nb) is the construction notebook for it, so that you can get a sense for how it works.

---

## Custom Curated Data Paclets

This answer is split into three parts, the basic setup (i.e. the answer to the question), an example, and a note on automating the process.

## Setup

This is exactly what the `` DataPaclets` `` functionality is built for. Our core data will be stored in a set of three paclets, two of which will define our data in [`WDX`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/WDX.html) and one will define our interface.

### Base Interface

We'll start with the interface as this tells us how to format our data. If we look at the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) for [`ElementData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ElementData.html) we see a pile of stuff in the `` DataPaclets`ElementDataDump` `` context. We can get most of the way to building our interface by simply copying these definitions into a separate .m file and replacing every instance of `ElementData` with our own data function, say `PackageData`. One thing to note is that you may see a `"DefaultProperty"` that the `*Data` interface loads. Set that to whatever property in your data you want to be the default, or, if you want to use the `Entity` framework set it to `None`.

There are a few extra things we'll need here, though. Notice that there's a function `` DataPaclets`ElementDataDump`Initialize ``. If we look at it's `DownValues` they define how we can load the base data from a data paclet. We can simply copy these over, but note that we'll need to copy over the [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html) attribute too.

There are then a few other functions for which we copy over the definitions (all in the `` DataPaclet`*Dump `` context):

```
handlePropertyError
StandardNameQ
GroupQ
FileQ
KeyQ
PropertyQ
CompiledPropertyQ
internalElementData
```

This will define most of our primary interface. We need one last thing before our interface is set-up, which is to set the initialization. Consider the [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues.html):

```
In[7]:= DataPaclets`ElementDataDump`$Properties // OwnValues

Out[7]= {HoldPattern[DataPaclets`ElementDataDump`$Properties] :> 
  DataPaclets`ElementDataDump`Initialize[
   DataPaclets`ElementDataDump`$Properties]}
```

We need to set this for all of the following:

```
{
 $Groups,
 $GroupHash,
 $PrivateGroups,
 $KeySource,
 $Keys,
 $SubgroupToGroup,
 $PropertyHash,
 $CompiledProperties,
 $SourceGroups,
 $StandardName,
 $Entities,
 $EntityHash,
 $Properties,
 ComputeFunction
 }
```

This is why that `HoldFirst` attribute was crucial. Without it setting

```
$Groups:=Intialize[$Groups]
```

throws iteration errors

### Data Index Paclet

Now we can set up our data.

First we need to set up a *Data_Index paclet which will contain a `Data` folder with the following:

```
{
 "Index.wdx",
 "Names.wdx",
 "Entities.wdx",
 "Properties.wdx",
 "Functions.wdx",
 "Groups.wdx",
 "PrivateGroups.wdx"
 }
```

Note that if you want to see example of usage for each you can just run this:

```
DataPaclets`ImportData[
 "*Data_Index",
 DataPaclets`GetDataPacletResource["*Data_Index", 
  "fname.wdx"
  ],
 All
 ]
```

where the `fname` is one of the preceding file names and the `*` is some type of data, say `Chemical`.

I'll give what needs to be exported to each of these files, anyway, though

#### Index.wdx

we export this expression:

```
{
 "Sources" -> {
   "Data" -> {
     "Part01" -> ents
     }
   },
 "Properties" -> {
   "Data" -> Thread@List@props
   }
 }
```

where `ents` is our list of entity names and `props` is our list of entity property names.

#### Names.wdx

```
{
 ...
 {canonicalName_i,...,alternateName_ij,...}
 ...
 }
```

where `canonicalName_i` is the `CanonicalName` for the ith [`Entity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html) and `alternateName_ij` is the jth alternate name for the canonical name.

#### Entities.wdx

```
Compress@
 Map[
  Hash[#, "Adler32"] -> # &,
  ents
  ]
```

This provides a numerical index to the entity name. I'm not sure using an `Integer` hash is necessary, but it seemed to be what was in some of the examples in the `$UserBasePacletsDirectory`.

#### Properties.wdx

```
Thread@List@props
```

Just the names of the properties. If a given property has a sub-property you list that as a successive element in the list, just like the `alternateNames` in the `"Entities.wdx"` file

```
{
 "Primary" -> {
  (HoldPattern[ComputeFunction[__]]:>___)...
  },
 "Helpers" -> {
  "OwnValues"->{
    fname->ov
    },
  "DownValues"->{
    fname->ov
    },
  ...
  }
 }
```

the `ComputeFunction` will be used as fallbacks (I think) in our `*Data` function. I just leave both of these lists empty. They do seem to be necessary, though. Leaving this entirely blanks throws errors.

#### Groups.wdx

```
{
 ...
 classname->{ ..., canonicalName_i, ...}
 ...
 }
```

This is how to define an [`EntityClass`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityClass.html) in the data, I think. Haven't used it (just left the list blank), but that's definitely the format one uses.

#### PrivateGroups.wdx

```
<same as Groups.wdx>
```

Presumably these are just never put in the public interface, but rather are only accessible via some inner functions. I just leave this blank.

### Data Paclet

Now we can do the actual core data:

The data should be chunked into small enough portions (it seems WRI uses ~2 mb?) that they can be quickly downloaded from a paclet server, if you're going to do server-based distribution, otherwise there's no reason not to just place all your data in a single WDX file.

Each chunk of the data should be exported to a `"Partnn.wdx"` in the `"Data"` subfolder of the `"*Data_Partnn"` data paclet.

Call that file `wdx`. We export it like this:

```
Export[wdx,
 {
  "Keys"->ents,
  "Properties"->Thread@List@props,
  "Data"->values
  },
 "DataTable"
 ]
```

where the `values` are just the values of the properties associated with each entity name in this chunk and the `ents` and `props` are identical to what's in `"Names.wdx"` and `"Properties.wdx"`, but restricted to only the entities in this chunk

### Usage / Entities

Note that this format means we only have to distribute two small paclets -- the interface and the index -- and the data can be downloaded in small chunks when necessary (although I have yet to plumb the details of how to set one's own download server -- something that will come later)

Then if someone uses our data function, e.g. `PackageData` they can use it like:

```
PackageData["BTools", "Name"]
```

or as

```
PackageData["BTools::ht1md", "Name"]
```

where that `BTools::ht1md` is the true `CanonicalName` and the other is an alternate name from the `"Names.wdx"` file.

So that's fun.

But the issue is that this doesn't link into the `Entity` framework and that's what really makes these `*Data` functions powerful. If we have version 11 this is okay though, because we can make an implicit entity store which just routes to our `*Data` function to look up properties.

We can set this up like:

```
EntityStore[
 dataTypeName -> <|
   "EntityValidationFunction" -> (True &),
   Join[
    <|
     "Label" -> <|
       "DefaultFunction" ->
        CanonicalName
       |>
     |>,
    AssociationMap[
     <|
       "DefaultFunction" ->
        EntityFramework`BatchApplied[
         Function[ents, dataFunction[ents, #]]
         ]
       |> &,
     props
     ]
    ]
   |>
 ]
```

where `dataTypeName` is the string name for our data type.

Then we append this to `` Internal`$DefaultEntityStores `` and we can link into the basic `Entity` framework. I copied that definition basically directly from the preloaded Earthquake `EntityStore` in there.

Then we'll need to vectorize our `*Data` looks to handle lists of entities, but this isn't bad. Simply go to the section of your definitions that deals with:

```
*Data[obj_]
```

and add

```
*Data[obj_List] := *Data[#] & /@ obj;
```

before it and then for for the section with:

```
*Data[obj_, prop__]
```

prepend

```
*Data[obj_List, prop__] :=
 *Data[#, prop] & /@ obj;
*Data[obj_, prop_List] :=
 *Data[obj, #] & /@ prop;
```

### Custom Servers

If you create a paclet server as detailed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132649/38205) (by the way if you want to distribute via a free Cloud account as I do see the answer after that one) you can don't even need to distribute the data -- just set up your server to serve the data paclets. `` DataPaclets`GetDataPacletResource `` will download parts as necessary, and it calls the `PacletManager` which will loop over the available paclet sites to find the appropriate data paclet.

### Version 10 (coming soon, hopefully)

For v10 I still need to dig further into how to hook into the `Entity` interface but I have some ideas.

---

## Example

I set up a set of these paclets in a cloud paclet server. The server has since been migrated, but the way it works is as follows. We install a paclet server, then install the main paclet and use `PacletSiteAdd` to allow Mathematica to look for the other paclets on our server.

Before it was migrated, the paclet server did this to install a `PackageData` paclet which would then load the `_Index` and `_Part01`. Then you could load it with `` <<PackageData` ``

And to search it:

```
In[46]:= PackageData["MaTeX"]

Out[46]= Entity["Package", "MaTeX"]
```

And then we could either work with the `Entity` or the `PackageData` function:

```
In[47]:= Entity["Package", "MaTeX"]["Author"]

Out[47]= "szhorvat"
```

---

## Automated Creation

We can also automate this process, since we can simply set up a template with all these definitions.

I do that [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/Packages/CuratedData.m).

Then if we have an [`EntityStore`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityStore.html) we can easily automate the creation of a curated data function as the `EntityStore` framework was undoubtedly built to work in a similar way.

The top-level function in that package (note that the package is not stand-alone) will loop through all the definitions in an `EntityStore` and export them to the appropriate paclets, although I haven't implemented the data chunking yet.